# How to get text from a <input> HTML control in FLEX 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a BorderContainer that has an HTML element inside of it. The HTML has a  control that isn't contained in a form.
 It is possible to retrive text from the **input** element at a given moment?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "given moment" can be determined in the HTML, then you can have your HTML fire a JavaScript event that your ActionScript can listen for.  More details here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=HandlingHTMLEvents_1.html

Hope that helps.